# Variable is used before being assigned

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to assign object by JSON object values and return it

```
interface Input {
    vehicles: Vehicle[];
    costs: Cost;
}

function readInput(fileName: string): Input{
    let input: Input;

    readFile(fileName, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        input = JSON.parse(data.toString("utf8"));
    });

    return input;
}
```

It appears an error that the input variable already "used" as `let input: Input`. This is from terminal with `tsc -w` command

```
src/input.ts(43,12): error TS2454: Variable 'input' is used before being assigned.
19:22:01 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Comment: Do you have `let input: Input` somewhere else in your code ?

Comment: `input` inside readInput() scope only

Comment: can you tell exact error and where you are getting it

Comment: Maybe, you can post more of your code. Nothing in the post indicates why you are getting the error.

Comment: readFile() is an **asynchronous** method. That's why it expects a callback function: to tell you when the file has been read, long after you've returned the undefined input from the method. You need to return a promise or an observable, or to accept a callback as argument, just like readFile() does.

Comment: thanks, the problem is I not return a promise or an observable. I'm reading this [article](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html)

Answer (score 3):

The only assignment made to `input` variable is inside callback function passed to `readFile`.

Typescript is unable to determine just from static type analysis that assignment will be made indeed (e.g. `if (err)` might be the case), or even decide whether callback function will be invoked at all (i.e. it is possible to implement `readFile` in such a way that it will never call your function.

Moreover, judging by the name of function `readFile` seems to be asynchronous, which means that it is likely that your callback will be invoked *after* `readInput()` has already finished its execution.

Taking all of that in account, Typescript is unable to guarantee that by the point of `return input;` the assignment to that variable would be made (and I'm rather convinced that it actually won't be).